Why C/C++ not scan my code folder instead only scan my Visual Studio folder?
When I use "Go To Definition" in *.c, it always jump to .h, not the function code in *.c.
After debug, I found the root cause is C/C++ not scan my code folder instead only scan my Visual Studio folder, here is the log:
LSP: (received) cpptools/resetDatabase
LSP: (invoked) cpptools/resetDatabase
Creating/updating compiler cache data tables (previously: 0)
Code browsing service initialized
Discovering files...
  Processing folder (recursive): C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\WINDOWS KITS\10\INCLUDE\10.0.19041.0\CPPWINRT\
  Processing folder (non-recursive): C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\VC\TOOLS\MSVC\14.29.30133\INCLUDE
  Processing folder (non-recursive): C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\VC\TOOLS\MSVC\14.29.30133\ATLMFC\INCLUDE
  Processing folder (recursive): C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\WINDOWS KITS\10\INCLUDE\10.0.19041.0\SHARED\
  Processing folder (recursive): C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\WINDOWS KITS\10\INCLUDE\10.0.19041.0\UCRT\
  Processing folder (recursive): C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\WINDOWS KITS\10\INCLUDE\10.0.19041.0\UM\
  Processing folder (recursive): C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\WINDOWS KITS\10\INCLUDE\10.0.19041.0\WINRT\
  Discovering files: 4871 file(s) processed
  0 file(s) removed from database
Done discovering files.
Parsing open files...
Populating include completion cache.
tag parsing file: D:\BHS-BIOS\Intel\ServerSiliconPkg\Library\CpuAndRevisionLib\CpuAndRevisionLib.c
Parsing remaining files...
  Parsing: 0 files(s) processed
Done parsing remaining files.
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt\winrt\base.h
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\algorithm
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\array
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\atomic
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\charconv
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\chrono
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\cstddef
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\iterator
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\limits
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\map
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\memory
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\new
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\optional
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\shared_mutex
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\string
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\string_view
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\stdexcept
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\tuple
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\type_traits
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\utility
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\unordered_map
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\vector
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\DirectXMath.h
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\WindowsNumerics.impl.h
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\yvals_core.h
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\xmemory
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\xutility
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\yvals.h
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\cstdint
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\cstring
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\xatomic.h
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\xatomic_wait.h
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\xthreads.h
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\intrin0.h
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\xbit_ops.h
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\xcharconv.h
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\xcharconv_ryu.h
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\stdint.h
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\stdio.h
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\assert.h
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\cmath
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\system_error
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\__msvc_chrono.hpp
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\__msvc_tzdb.hpp
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\compare
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\forward_list
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\istream
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\sstream
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\xloctime
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\concepts
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\format
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\iomanip
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\stddef.h
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\xtr1common
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\iosfwd
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\cfloat
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\climits
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\cwchar
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\isa_availability.h
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\xstddef
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\xtree
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\xpolymorphic_allocator.h
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\exception
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\typeinfo
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\vcruntime_new.h
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\initializer_list
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\xsmf_control.h
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\mutex
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\condition_variable
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\xstring
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\cctype
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\xhash
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\math.h
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\float.h
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\intrin.h
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\xmmintrin.h
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\emmintrin.h
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\pmmintrin.h
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\smmintrin.h
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\immintrin.h
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\arm64_neon.h
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\arm_neon.h
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared\sal.h
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\sal.h
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\DirectXMathConvert.inl
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\DirectXMathVector.inl
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\DirectXMathMatrix.inl
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\DirectXMathMisc.inl
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\WindowsNumerics.inl
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\vcruntime.h
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\xkeycheck.h
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\cstdlib
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\crtdbg.h
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\crtdefs.h
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\use_ansi.h
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\string.h
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\xtimec.h
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\intrin0.inl.h
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\xerrc.h
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\xcharconv_ryu_tables.h
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\corecrt.h
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\corecrt_wstdio.h
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\__msvc_system_error_abi.hpp
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\cerrno
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\xcall_once.h
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\ctime
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\ratio
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\bit
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\ostream
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\xlocnum
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\locale
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\xfilesystem_abi.h
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\xlocmon
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\cstdio
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\limits.h
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\wchar.h
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\xnode_handle.h
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\malloc.h
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\vcruntime_exception.h
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\vcruntime_typeinfo.h
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\thread
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\stop_token
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\ctype.h
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\list
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\corecrt_math.h
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\corecrt_math_defines.h
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\setjmp.h
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\ammintrin.h
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\mm3dnow.h
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\armintr.h
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\arm64intr.h
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\mmintrin.h
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\tmmintrin.h
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\wmmintrin.h
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\zmmintrin.h
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared\concurrencysal.h
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\concurrencysal.h
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\vadefs.h
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\stdlib.h
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\vcruntime_new_debug.h
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\corecrt_memory.h
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\corecrt_wstring.h
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\vcruntime_string.h
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared\winapifamily.h
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\corecrt_stdio_config.h
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\errno.h
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\time.h
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\ios
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\streambuf
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\xlocbuf
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\xlocmes
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\corecrt_memcpy_s.h
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\corecrt_wconio.h
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\corecrt_wctype.h
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\corecrt_wdirect.h
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\corecrt_wio.h
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\corecrt_wprocess.h
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\corecrt_wstdlib.h
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\corecrt_wtime.h
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\sys\stat.h
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\sys\types.h
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\corecrt_malloc.h
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\eh.h
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\process.h
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\setjmpex.h
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\nmmintrin.h
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\corecrt_search.h
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared\winpackagefamily.h
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\xiosbase
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\corecrt_share.h
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\corecrt_terminate.h
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\corecrt_startup.h
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\share.h
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\xlocale
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\vcruntime_startup.h
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\xfacet
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\xlocinfo
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\xlocinfo.h
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\clocale
tag parsing file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\locale.h
Done parsing open files.


Actually I have a code folder like this:
enter image description here
I have no idea to solve this.

It has nothing to do with the .vscode/c_cpp_properties.json because I tried to delete it.
I put the same code folder from remote SSH server (Windows) to local Windows system, the issue disappeared.
Uninstall VS Code Server and install it again (so re-install the C/C++ extension), issue still happen


I raised an issue report here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/12784
